# Pine-script How to get the y-coordinate of a crossover

Tags: pine-script

```
//@version=4
study(title="Stochastic RSI", shorttitle="Stoch RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")
smoothK = input(3, "K", minval=1)
smoothD = input(3, "D", minval=1)
lengthRSI = input(14, "RSI Length", minval=1)
lengthStoch = input(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")
rsi1 = rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = sma(stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = sma(k, smoothD)
plot(k, "K", color=#2962FF)
plot(d, "D", color=#FF6D00)
```

This is the default script for the stochastic RSI. How do I get the y-coordinate when k and d crosses?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that sometimes you would not get accurate crossing value, as crossing might not appear in the bar with current calculation (you have just values in the bars, e.g. `[2 4]` , `[6 3]` , so they are crossing (somewhere).

```
c = cross(k,d)

var float crossPrice = na
if (c) 
    crossPrice := k  // k or d
    label.new(bar_index, k, text = tostring( crossPrice ))
```

same

```
c = cross(k,d)

label.new(c? bar_index : na, k, text = tostring( valuewhen(c, k,0) ))
```

Comment: I guess its impossible to get the exact y-coordinate at the point of intersection of k and d. Thank you though.